# zend framework 2 module routing

Tags: php, url, zend-framework2

I've created module `BookList` and on `localhost/book` I am getting error:

```
 "The requested URL /book was not found on this server."
```

When I try to open `localhost/application` I get the error:

```
 Not Found<br>
 The requested URL /application was not found on this server.<br>
 Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I have confirmed that my **zendskeleton-application** is in fact working:

[image]

I solved it by configuring Apache config  by setting AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0):

have you setup the router in module.config.php?

like in
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html

Comment: Are you seeking details from the asker or offering resolving advice?

Answer (score 0):

> If you have created module yourself (without using command prompt), you should add your **"module name"** in *ProjectName/config/autoload/application.config.php* and add your module name in it. i.e,

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'Application',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        ),
    ),
);
```

> In the return array, under 'modules', add your module name and it will work correctly, if any problem, feel free to ask.

Comment: I solved it by configuring Apache config by setting AllowOverride All. Thank you for help anyway